# Unable to import external key into Azure Key Vault

Tags: openssl, azure-keyvault

I followed the same steps as mentioned in this issue.
[Import key in azure key vault. BYOK using the openssl command instead an vendor HSM tool](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/108113)

1.Generate and download the KEK (Key Encryption Key) as documented
`az keyvault key create --vault-name byok-vault-hsm --name byok-kek-key --kty RSA-HSM --size 2048 --ops import`
`az keyvault key download--vault-name byok-vault-hsm--name byok-kek-key--file KEK.pem`

2. As vaguely described in the documentation, I generated a target RSA key and an ephemeral AES key using the openssl command.

```
openssl genrsa -out byok.pem 2048
openssl rand -out temp-aes-key.key 32
```

2.1 Convert the target key to DER format

`openssl pkcs8 -inform PEM -outform DER -in byok.pem -out byok.der -nocrypt`

3. Wrap the target key with ephemeral AES key using the CKM_RSA_AES_KEY_WRAP_PAD

```
export EPHEMERAL_AES_HEX=$( hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x"' < temp-aes-key.key )

openssl enc -id-aes256-wrap-pad -iv A65959A6 -K $EPHEMERAL_AES_HEX -in byok.der -out key.byok
```

4.Wrap the ephemeral AES key with the KEK from KeyVault

`openssl pkeyutl -encrypt -pubin -inkey KEK.pem -in temp-aes-key.key -out wrapped-temp-key.byok -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:oaep -pkeyopt rsa_oaep_md:sha1 -pkeyopt rsa_mgf1_md:sha1`

5.Concatenate the both wrapped key together and base64 the result

```
cat wrapped-temp-key.byok key.byok > final-key.byok
cat final-key.byok | base64 | tr '/+' '_-' | tr -d '=' > ciphertext.byok
```

6. Create the BYOK blob JSON file as described in the documentation

```
{
  "schema_version": "1.0.0",
  "header":
  {    "kid": "https..................",
    "alg": "dir",
    "enc": "CKM_RSA_AES_KEY_WRAP"  },  
    "ciphertext":"NXb8CJBxXo9gxdVrs3_rLnDJvlCkWtYkLFPchfhGAjF4xuJHn2GQwLfZY5DpgTuqBP1XztD7ph32XYf80HlauyvCaaUQa9UOF0VbfzXKXpFvq9TYCFyT7Qh3TfQcGr7ihEVw6QJ1nkCgNbFmsrMzG4y9Bp..............",
  "generator": "BYOK tool aemsec; source HSM aemsec"
}
```

7. Import the BYOK into KeyVault
   `az keyvault key import --vault-name key-vault-name --name aemsec-byok-key --byok-file byok.byok --ops encrypt decrypt --debug`

The import command returns the following error:

knack.util.CLIError: (BadParameter) Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.
Code: BadParameter
Message: Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.

cli.azure.cli.core.azclierror: (BadParameter) Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.
Code: BadParameter
Message: Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.
az_command_data_logger: (BadParameter) Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.
Code: BadParameter
Message: Unable to import BYOK blob with this KEK.

Can anyone please assists how to fix this?